# Xcode Issue Navigator says "Value stored to BOOL during its initialization is never read"

Tags: ios, boolean

I declared BOOL REDguy in ViewController.h

In my ViewController.m file under viewDidLoad method I have the following code...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:REDguy forKey:@"save"];

if (REDguy==[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]) {
    MAN.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"RED.png"];
}
   BOOL REDguy=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
```

The above code does exactly what I want it to do perfectly. However, in Xcode's Product --> Analyze, I'm getting a message in Issue Navigator stating...

"Value stored to REDguy during its initialization is never read"

I understand that it's referring to me adding the word BOOL in front of REDguy, but without adding it, nothing works. Can I ignore the Issue Navigator message, will Apple reject my app if I do? Why is Issue Navigator saying it's never read, when everything works fine on all devices?

Comment: this has nothing to do with either Xcode or Apple rejecting/approving your app. This is a compiler warning, which you get presumably because you never use the `REDguy` variable. That's probably not what you want. Since `REDguy` seems to be an instance variable, you don't need to (shouldn't) re-declare it as a local variable.

Comment: I have no choice.  If I don't reuse BOOL word, what I want doesn't work. Btw, this DOES have something to do with apple approval, rejection because i'm asking if I leave this issue navigator problem,  will Apple reject my app based on me leaving that problem?

Comment: Read the comment above carefully again - it already states EVERYTHING you need to know. It fixes your code problem AND answers your question wether or not it will be rejected.

Comment: The first comment doesn't help at all. I know I shouldn't have to re-declare the BOOL. I've used REDguy without BOOL a dozen times in my project. However, for the above particular code for some reason without using BOOL for that particular saving purpose, the save doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring REDGuy as a local variable then not using it, that is the reason for the message. End of story. There is no other reason. Exactly as The Croissant says in his comment.

Now you say: "If I don't reuse BOOL word, what I want doesn't work."

So obviously you having to reuse the BOOL word is the incorrect way of sorting out whatever: "what I want doesn't work." is.

You don't say what "what I want doesn't work." is. Whatever the problem is, re-using the BOOL word is not the correct solution. You can already see its not the correct solution because you are getting a compilation warning, but even if you are not getting that warning it is still the incorrect solution because you have shadowed the the REDGuy instance variable with a REDGuy local variable.

You say: "I know I shouldn't have to re-declare the BOOL" but then you do it anyway. ???!!???

Open a new question and describe what "what I want doesn't work."  means and then solve THAT problem correctly then THIS problem will be irrelevant.

Comment: With NSUserDefaults StandardUserDefaults i'm trying to save the BOOL during the game. If he user clicks on the BOOL inside a UIButton the BOOL is now saved throughout the entire game. When I removed the BOOL word from the front of REDGuy, I get no warnings but now the saving doesn't work. When I added BOOL in front of REDGuy, I get warning and save works.

That's why I'm confused. I do use REDGuy over a dozen times in my project but only when it comes to that ONE code line where I put BOOL word in front of REDGuy, there's an issue.

Comment: You should post a new question, in particular show the definition of REDGuy. By the way I don't know what you're trying to do with that code, first you save RedGuy to defaults, then you compare RedGuy's value against the synchronize method then you read the value you just stored right back into Redguy.